# HTML5 player video won't stream when deployed

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Following code works ok on local IIS but when deployed video aren't streaming anymore (they are downloaded and then played). Looks like it's a server configuration or project configuration problem. Can anyone help or give me a lead?

```
try
            {
                ScreenDefinition sd = handler.Get();
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                if (Format == "Ogg")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "video/ogg";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", sd.Ogg.Length.ToString());
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=video.ogg");
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(sd.Ogg.ToArray(), 0, sd.Ogg.Length);
                }
                else {
                    Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", sd.WhatCanKADoScreenMp4.Length.ToString());
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=video.mp4");
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(sd.Mp4.ToArray(), 0, sd.Mp4.Length);
                }
                Response.End();
            }
            catch
            {
                //videos streaming was canceled by user
                //log it
            }
```

Code in View:

```
<video width="400" height="300" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" style="margin-left: 270px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <source src="@Url.Action("GetVideoStream", new { Format = "Mp4" })" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="@Url.Action("GetVideoStream", new { Format = "Ogg" })" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking to do is to enable Progressive downloads on your server. I don't know anything about your config but a google search will yield good results.

Some more information: http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html

Comment: Thank you on your fast response. I'll try to research. ty